# Umlet is not working in jsf

Tags: jsf, character-encoding, facelets

I am using xhtml and jsf combination.
If I enter umlet character in text box it chage to other code.
Suppose i give ö it change to Ã¶.
Can please any body help me?
Is need to include any tag for umlet in jsf?

Answer (score 2):

Facelets uses UTF-8 by default to write the characters to the response, so this issue should not be caused by Facelets. Apparently the file *itself* is saved with the wrong encoding by your file editor. To be precise, in CP-1252 instead of UTF-8. Explore the editor settings to change it to UTF-8. In Eclipse for example, you can find it in *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding*.